# Ranking at Multiple Levels on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've read a few ways of doing this, but it does not seem to work for me. I'm trying to pull data that has a Category, Itemcode, and Sales.  I'm summing this up for a period of time so that my basic query looks like this:

```
select 
    Category
    , Itemcode
    , sum(Sales)
    , rank() over (partition by Category order by sum(Sales) desc) as ItemRank
from 
    Sales
group by 
    Category, Itemcode
```

When I do that, my data looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is to add another rank that would show the rank of the Category as a whole.

Something like this:

[image]

What would the query look like with that added in?  I've tried several things, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: You can have multiple RANK() columns as long as your grouping criteria is the same. Can you post your attempt that did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a guess here, but I gather you want to rank based on the TotalSales? If so, you can join to a subquery to do the aggregation, then use that in another rank column:

```
declare @Sales table (Category varchar(25), ItemCode int, Sales int)

insert into @Sales 
values
    ('Category A', 123, 100),
    ('Category A', 234, 125),
    ('Category A', 345,  97),
    ('Category B', 456, 354),
    ('Category B', 567, 85),
    ('Category B', 678, 112)
    
select 
s.Category
, Itemcode
, sum(s.Sales)
, rank() over (partition by s.Category order by sum(Sales) desc) as ItemRank
, dense_rank() over (order by sum(TotalSales) desc) as CategoryRank
from @Sales s
join    (   select Category, sum(Sales) as TotalSales 
            from @Sales 
            group by Category
        ) d
on s.Category = d.Category

group by s.Category, Itemcode
```